# Getting error on using getcurrentlocation in ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

I’m trying to find geolocation in ionic 3. when i use geolocaton "getcurrentlocation()" not working. It is showing error like below and i don’t know how to solve this issue.Below is code.

[image]

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { GeolocationOptions, Geoposition } from 
'@ionicnative/geolocation' ;


@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {

currentPos : Geoposition;
constructor(
public navCtrl: NavController,
public navParams: NavParams,
private geolocation: Geolocation
) {

}

ionViewDidEnter(){
this.getUserPosition();
}  

getUserPosition(){

this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((pos : Geoposition) => {

    this.currentPos = pos;      
    console.log(pos);

},(err : PositionError)=>{
    console.log("error : " + err.message);
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add catch in your block like below:

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
 // resp.coords.latitude
 // resp.coords.longitude
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('Error getting location', error);
});
```

in `resp` you will get current location coordinates.

Hope this will helps.

Comment: it's not working.Please see the image that error is coming even if i use your code.

Comment: where you update your image I can still see old image in your question.

Comment: ya after update my code i'm facing the same issue like old image.

Comment: Can you add full code of your .ts file i think its related to some other error. Please add code not screen shot.

Comment: Hope you already done plugin installation and import proper file for Geolocation.